# Create a type in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, types

I was trying to make a basket of products and i need to create a type in sqlite like:

create type B_productes as object (
    id_product integer,
    quantity    integer
    );

Or if you can give other solution.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know, one solution would be to is to create another table of type B_products and use, a value from main product as **foreign key**, in table 2. So hence you can link both tables, instead of creating a table inside a table.
I think this is the most easiest and widely used method, 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp
 Hope this helps :)